# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds but item is being logged

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to create a `JSONObject` but I am getting some weird results.

I am using this `for` loop

```
Object[] q = null;
Deque<String> queue = new ArrayDeque<String>();
if(queue.size() > 7){
    queue.remove();
}
queue.add(aux);
q = queue.toArray();
for(int i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
   String[] temp = q[i].toString().split(",");
   logger.info(temp[2]);
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
   json.put("stamp", temp[0]);
   json.put("zone", temp[1]);
   json.put("name", temp[2]);
   json.put("val", temp[3]);
   jArray2.put(json);
 }
```

But I am getting this error in the server log:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at publicwebsite.util.PieChartData.getCSV(PieChartData.java:114)
```

As you can see I'm logging the result of `temp[2]` which is where the error is. In the app log however `temp[2]` is being logged successfully:

```
2015-10-28 18:55:37,031 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "apples"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "oranges"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "pears"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "pineapples"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "strawberries"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "plumbs"
2015-10-28 18:55:37,033 [ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2] INFO  publicwebsite.util.PieChartData - "berries"
```

**Output of** `logger.info(Arrays.toString(q));`

```
[2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"apples",9707, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"oranges",1799, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"pears",1961, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"pineapples",4669, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"strawberries",245, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"plumbs",367, 2015-09-07 04:00:00,EDT,"berries",550
```

How can there be an Array out of bounds error when the logs show that there is obviously something there?

Comment: The line `logger.info(temp[2]);` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the length of the array is less than `3`, so those logs must come from smaller `i` values. Try logging `Arrays.toString(temp)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `temp[2]` but a few lines later you access

```
 json.put("val", temp[3]);
```

Better:

```
 if ( temp.length > 3 )
       json.put("val", temp[3]);
```

**Bottomline**

When using`.split()` on data coming from outside of the program and working with literal static indices, you need to check the length prior, Silent assumption that the length is always equal to your highest index always lead to such errors.

Comment: But the index that causes the exception is `2`, not `3`.

Comment: THAT WAS AN EXAMPLE - you may do that with any index between 0 and ∞

Comment: There's no need for the capital letters. But if you want to avoid an exception on `temp[3]` you need to check that `temp.length > 3` anyway.

Comment: I've made it `temp[1]` and still get the same error on `index: 1`

Comment: Your String Array `temp` is either empty or has only 1 element. Check the code before, that looks strange to me: Where is `aux` coming from and what is in there?

Answer (score 0):

There may be another class instance in the application server that is writing to the log or another JVM is running.
Something else writes to the log it seems.